# How to use "grep" command to find text including subdirectories

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to find all files which contain a specific string of text. The `grep` command works, but I don't know how to use it for every directory (I can only do it for my current directory). I tried reading `man grep`, but it didn't yield any help.

Comment: grep -RIn <yor pattern> * Will search from current directories down in all text files.
Not sure how to do my search recursively in file patterns like *.C with only grep

Comment: Wildcard with `--include="*.C"` option, @user311346, thanks to @Lekensteyn.

Comment: Use the find and grep combination to recursively search files for a string in current and all sub directories. Check this http://wilddiary.com/find-files-containing-my-text/

Answer (score 664, accepted):

It would be better to use

```
grep -rl "string" /path
```

where

- `-r` (or `--recursive`) option is used to traverse also all sub-directories of `/path`, whereas
- `-l` (or `--files-with-matches`) option is used to only print filenames of matching files, and not the matching lines (this could also improve the speed, given that `grep` stop reading a file at first match with this option).

Comment: Actually if "string" is a text pattern to find, it's better to use that functionality, otherwise someone can face problems when the string contains dot or special character which has meaning in regular expressions and not just a dot which should be found as a string, as-is. Then I would use `-rlF` switches, `-F` for "fixed string" (and not regexp - for example). Of course, if the task was using regexps, then excuse me. Sure, the same theory without -r too, I often see that people assumes grep searches "text" and it can cause problems which special ones which mean something as a regexp.

Comment: There is also the `-i` flag which ignores case.

Comment: I would only to show the `--recursive` option, there are ton of options and usage scenarios one can talk about. I started from the @dmityugov accepted  answer and modified to work without `find`.

Comment: I would appreciate if you include the meaning of the command in your answer, e.g. the meaning of the options `-rl`.

Comment: @N.N.: done :-)

Comment: It would be really helpful if you also either mentioned @LGB's comment that your string is not a plain string, but rather a regexp, and about the `F` "fixed string" option.

Comment: How do you specify only certain types of files, like header (*.h) files?

Comment: @ScottBiggs: with the option `--include '*.h'`

Comment: This is the first grep command I've ever seen that actually makes sense. Not to hate on the all powerful grep. Long live grep.

Answer (score 216):

If you're looking for lines matching in files, my favorite command is:

```
grep -Hrn 'search term' path/to/files
```

- `-H` causes the filename to be printed (implied when multiple files are searched)
- `-r` does a recursive search
- `-n` causes the line number to be printed

`path/to/files` can be `.` to search in the current directory

Further options that I find very useful:

- `-I` ignore binary files (complement: `-a` treat all files as text)
- `-F` treat `search term` as a literal, not a regular expression
- `-i` do a case-insensitive search
- `--color=always` to force colors even when piping through `less`. To make `less` support colors, you need to use the `-r` option:

  ```
  grep -Hrn search . | less -r
  ```
- `--exclude-dir=dir` useful for excluding directories like `.svn` and `.git`.

[image: Example output]

Comment: `-H` on a folder is redundant, if there is more then one file, as is probable. In fact, the man page says `-H, --with-filename: Print the file name for each match. This is the default when there is more than one file to search.`

Comment: I did not know that, it always worked like I expected. It's my default command when looking for files.

Comment: Is there a way to only consider files with a, say, .a extention (and to combine this with -r)?

Comment: @user2413 Try `--include '*.*'`

Comment: @enzotib Just a FYI: I don't get the nice clean output of every line in every file where my text appears with -rln nor -rl, but I do with -Hrn. Redundant or not, it looks like the screenshot above with the -Hrn options. Also, it doesn't seem like -n works without -H.

Comment: @SgtPooki the `-l` option prints just the file name, not the line (number) themselves.

Comment: I know. The -n prints the line number. But not without -H

Comment: @SgtPooki On my system (`grep` version 2.18), `grep -n key file` shows line numbers before each line (without file name). `grep -nH key file` prints the filename, line number and line. `grep -rn key .` prints the filename, line number and line for every file recursively.

Comment: @Lekensteyn you're right. the -l option breaks the -n option. (GNU grep 2.6.3)

Comment: How could I ignore files ending with `~`? @Lekensteyn

Comment: @alper Try `grep --exclude='*~' ...`

Answer (score 26):

I believe you can use something like this:

```
find /path -type f -exec grep -l "string" {} \;
```

**Explanation from comments**

`find` is a command that lets you find files and other objects like directories and links in subdirectories of a given path. If you don't specify a mask that filesnames should meet, it enumerates all directory objects.

- `-type f` specifies that it should process only files, not directories etc.
- `-exec grep` specifies that for every found file, it should run the grep command, passing its filename as an argument to it, by replacing `{}` with the filename

Comment: Just for those who don't know, adding `-name '*.py'` restricts the matches to files ending in '.py'.

Comment: I like that this covers clients that don't have -R implemented in their grep command.

Comment: If you want the matching line AND filename printed, make exec like: `... -exec bash -c 'grep -r "mystring" {} && echo {}' \;`

Comment: what's the relative perf to just using grep directly?

Comment: @Donn Lee think its better to `-exec bash -c 'grep -H "pattern" $1' _ {} \;`

Comment: @DanielF It's now ```--include='*.py'``` instead of  ```-name '*.py'```

Answer (score 25):

My default command is

```
grep -Rin string *
```

I use a capitol 'R' because `ls` uses it for recursive. Since grep accepts both, no reason to not use it.

EDIT: per HVNSweeting, apparently `-R` will follow symlinks where as `-r` will not.

Comment: To search in hidden files too, run `shopt -s dotglob` (remember `-s` as "set"). Be careful when removing files then. If you've dotglob enabled, `rm -r *` removes everything in the current dir, but *also* the directory above it because `..` matches. To disable dotglob, use `shopt -u dotglob` ("unset"). The changes are temporary though, it only applies to the current shell.

Comment: I forgot about this. Is there a way to set it for one the one line? something like `shopt -s dotglob & <grep cmd> & shopt -y dotglob` only more convenient? This way we won't have to worry about resetting it

Comment: Also, it's probably easier to use `grep -Rin string .` in most of these cases. I just use * because it seems to come more naturally.

Comment: `shops -s dotglob;grep -Rin string *;shopt -u dotglob` works.

Comment: yeah... but.. it'd be nice if there was a command that only worked for the single line. instead of turning it on and off in the same line, whjich is silly

Comment: `bash -c 'shopt -s dotglob;grep -Rin string *'`, but now it gets dirty. Just use `grep -Rin string .`

Comment: if you do recursive grep, then you can just start from "." instead of "*". no dotglob needed.

Comment: vote up this, one thing doesn't mention in manpage is ``R`` will follow symbolic links, ``r`` does not

Answer (score 13):

If you’re willing to try something new, give [**`ack`**](http://betterthangrep.com/) a shot. The command to recursively search the current directory for `string` is:

```
ack string
```

Installation is quite simple:

```
curl http://betterthangrep.com/ack-standalone > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3
```

(Provided you’ve already got the directory `~/bin` and it’s preferably in your `PATH`.)

Comment: Or just apt-get install ack-grep (, and add alias ack=ack-grep to your .bashrc)

Comment: What do the last parameters to the `chmod` command do? Are they specific for `chmod` or are they bash related (the `!#:3` part)?

Comment: @ElliottDarfink That’s using Bash’s [history feature](http://ss64.com/bash/history.html) – `!` is an *event designator*. They’re pretty powerful to avoid repetitions. `!#:3` references the third token of the command line so far, i.e. `~/bin/ack` in this case.

Answer (score 6):

#### [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/grep) ([GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) or [BSD](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep))

You can use `grep` tool to search recursively the current folder with `-r` parameter, like:

```
grep -r "pattern" .
```

<sup>Note: `-r` - Recursively search subdirectories.</sup>

To search within specific files, you can use a [globbing syntax](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) such as:

```
grep "class foo" **/*.c
```

<sup>Note: By using [globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (`**`), it scans all the files recursively with specific extension or pattern. **To enable this syntax, run: [`shopt -s globstar`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/793715/55075).** You may also use `**/*.*` for all files (excluding hidden and without extension) or any other pattern.</sup>

If you've the error that your argument is too long, consider narrowing down your search, or use `find` syntax instead such as:

```
find . -name "*.php" -execdir grep -nH --color=auto foo {} ';'
```

Alternatively use [`ripgrep`](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/).

#### [`ripgrep`](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/)

If you're working on larger projects or big files, you should use `ripgrep` instead, like:

```
rg "pattern" .
```

<sup>Checkout the docs, installation steps or source code on the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep).</sup>

It's much quicker than any other tool like [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/)/[BSD](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep) [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/grep), [`ucg`](https://github.com/gvansickle/ucg), [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), [`sift`](https://github.com/svent/sift), [`ack`](https://github.com/petdance/ack2), [`pt`](https://github.com/monochromegane/the_platinum_searcher) or similar, since it is built on top of [Rust's regex engine](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex) which uses finite automata, SIMD and aggressive literal optimizations to make searching very fast.

It supports ignore patterns specified in `.gitignore` files, so a single file path can be matched against multiple glob patterns simultaneously.

---

You can use the common parameters such as:

- `-i` - Insensitive searching.
- `-I` - Ignore the binary files.
- `-w` - Search for the whole words (in opposite of partial word matching).
- `-n` - Show the line of your match.
- `-C`/`--context` (e.g. `-C5`) - Increases context, so you see the surrounding code .
- `--color=auto` - Mark up the matching text.
- `-H` - Displays filename where the text is found.
- `-c` - Displays count of matching lines. Can be combined with `-H`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `rg` tool.

Answer (score 4):

The command rgrep is dedicated for such need

If not available, you can get it like this

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cd ~/bin
wget http://sdjf.esmartdesign.com/files/rgrep
chmod +x rgrep
```

You can directly set into your default grep options as described above.

I personnaly use

```
[[  ${#args} -lt 5 && "${args//[[:space:]]/}" == "-i" ]] && args="-Hin"
args="${args:--Hns} --color=auto"
```

related topic : [how to always use rgrep with color](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378932/how-to-always-use-rgrep-with-color)

Comment: rgrep is provided by the grep package which is installed by default in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I do this using xargs, a very underrated command

```
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'string_you_are_looking_for'
```

find ./ gives you a recursive list of all the files in a current folder
then you pipe it to xargs that executes the grep command on each one of those files

Comment: Using  `xargs` without `-print0` option to `find` and `-0` option to `xargs` is deprecated, it will fail on filenames containing spaces.

Comment: @enzotib I have edited the answer as you suggested.- please review and if needs to editing and correcting, I will happy re-editing by you. thank you

Comment: @KasiyA: it is ok now, removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2:**

This line of commands using `find` and `grep` fixes the problem:

```
$ find path_to_search_in -type f -exec grep -in searchString {} 2> /dev/null +
```

`--color=<always or auto>` for colored output:

```
$ find path_to_search_in -type f \
            -exec grep --color=always -in searchString {} 2>/dev/null +
```

Example:

```
$ find /tmp/test/ -type f -exec grep --color=auto -in "Search string" {} 2>/dev/null +
```

An example run in the snapshot below:
[image: snap1]

---

**Update 1:**

You can try following code; as a function in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` or in a script:

> ```
> wherein () 
> { 
>     for i in $(find "$1" -type f 2> /dev/null);
>     do
>         if grep --color=auto -i "$2" "$i" 2> /dev/null; then
>             echo -e "\033[0;32mFound in: $i \033[0m\n";
>         fi;
>     done
> }
> ```

Usage: `wherein /path/to/search/in/ searchkeyword`

example:

```
$ wherein ~/Documents/ "hello world"
```

(Note: As suggested in the comments below by @enzotib, this doesn't work with file/directories including spaces in their names.)

---

*Original post*

To search for the string and output just that line with the search string:

```
$ for i in $(find /path/of/target/directory -type f); do \
    grep -i "the string to look for" "$i"; done
```

e.g.:

```
$ for i in $(find /usr/share/applications -type f); \
    do grep -i "web browser" "$i"; done
```

To display filename containing the search string:

```
$ for i in $(find /path/of/target/directory -type f); do \
    if grep -i "the string to look for" "$i" > /dev/null; then echo "$i"; fi; done;
```

e.g.:

```
$ for i in $(find /usr/share/applications -type f); \
    do if grep -i "web browser" "$i" > /dev/null; then echo "$i"; \
    fi; done;
```

Comment: Fails on filenames containing spaces. The failing is hided by the fact that stderr is not shown.

Comment: @enzotib thanks for pointing that out.. that's still unresolved for the function specified.. I've added another one-liner though..

Comment: Now the answer is similar to that of @dmityugov.

Comment: yes, but in that sense most of the answers in this page if you check are similar in respect that they use `grep`, next to that being the subset using `find` with `grep`... but if you are to accept different switches and tweaks as a distinct answer, probably mine will fit in here too.. or do you differ? the last update does what I'd like in my search: file names with lines with search key and line no. too :) and colored output and error filter for better readability..

Answer (score 0):

I know there are plenty of answers here, but here's an alternative if you'd like to add other restrictions when searching the files:

```
find . -type f -exec grep --quiet string_to_look_for {} ';' -print
```

This works because `grep` will return 0 if it found a result, 1 otherwise. For example you can find files 1 MB large *and* containing something:

```
find . -type f -exec grep --quiet string_to_look_for {} ';' -size 1M -print
```

For multiple requirements you probably want to use the optimizer flag `-O` that exists in GNU grep.

Answer (score 0):

A script (find-in-code) to search in C, CPP code:

```
#!/bin/sh

find . \( -iname "*.c" -o -iname "*.cpp" -o -iname "*.h" \) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color -n "$1"
```

Use:

```
find-in-code "search string"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very fast alternative to grep called the Platinum Searcher. You can download it [here](https://github.com/monochromegane/the_platinum_searcher).