# usb drive wiped during install

Tags: data-recovery

Yeah I tried to install ubuntu on my computer and instead it wiped my USB drive (which has critical files) and now there's ubuntu 'installed' on my USB drive.

How do I get my files back?!?!

Answer (score 3):

Data recovery tools e.g. [**Testdisk**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk] can recover data from any medium including an USB stick.

The included tool [**Photorec**](https://askubuntu.com/a/94431/3940) will recover remnants of individual files but file names and directories will have to be restored manually.

Answers to this question may help you finding text files from a phrase they may contain:

[How to use "grep" command to find text including subdirectories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55325/how-to-use-grep-command-to-find-text-including-subdirectories)

Comment: Looks like Photorec is actually working, but I'm getting a whole bunch of text files and gobbledygook out of it heh and I'm not so sure what to do with these text files... it DID recover mp3 files and pngs but they're not the important files. I need a specific text file recovered.